# Call function on ButtonClick

Tags: javascript, c#, webforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I am trying to call function from `.aspx` to my `JavaScript`. 
I try something like this

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Filter" Width="224px" OnClientClick="return BindToData();" />
```

And here is my JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function GetSelectedReportName() {
        return
        document.getElementById('<%=ddlReportName.ClientID%>').options[document.getElementById('<%=ddlReportName.ClientID%>').selectedIndex].value;
    }

    function ShowReport() {
        var reportName = GetSelectedReportName();
        ASPxWebDocumentViewer1.OpenReport(reportName);
    }

</script>
```

And here is my function which I need to call in `ButtonClick`

```
public void BindToData()
{
    try
    {
        string connString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DesignSaoOsig1;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string strproc = "TestReport";
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(strproc, connString))
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            sda.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = ddlStatus.SelectedValue == "1" ? true : false;
            sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@OrgJed", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlOrgUnit.SelectedValue;
            sda.Fill(ds);

            XtraReport report = new XtraReport
            {
                DataSource = ds,
                DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName
            };

            string[] arrvalues = new string[ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count];

            for (int loopcounter = 0; loopcounter < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; loopcounter++)
            {
                //assign dataset values to array
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["PrezimeIme"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["NetworkLogin"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["Status"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["OrgUnitID"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["DT_Creat"].ToString();
                arrvalues[loopcounter] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[loopcounter]["DT_Modif"].ToString();
            }

            ASPxWebDocumentViewer1.OpenReport(report);
            ASPxWebDocumentViewer1.DataBind();

            //gridview1.DataSource = ds;
            //gridview1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I need to load filtered report in button click, since in `JS` I only load report, when I click in button I get only unfiltered data, when I debug application I see that I get filtered data, but problem can be only in `JS`. Any help will be appreciate

Here is reference page which I check:

[Link 1](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T758611/html-js-dashboard-how-to-get-selected-filter-value)

[Link 2](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t429867/aspxwebdocumentviewer-how-to-invoke-the-print-command-when-a-report-is-loaded-in-a-browser)

[Link 3](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t594642/how-to-load-a-report-to-the-aspxwebdocumentviewer-control-at-runtime)

Comment: you cannot call server side method using `OnClientClick`

Comment: `OnClientClick="return BindToData();`  what is use this method then ?

Comment: you need to understand the difference between client side code that runs in browser and the server side code which runs on web server

Comment: I already now difference man !

Comment: I google it and I found method `OnClientClick` which mat help me, but doesnt work !

Comment: What do the docs say about using `ASPxWebDocumentViewer1` should you load the report server side or client side? You are trying to load it client side, but I don't think you have a reference to `ASPxWebDocumentViewer1` in the client. That looks like the server.

Comment: As I see from example  from their docs it could be loaded also from client side.

Comment: The problem here is that I load report using `ASPXWebDocumentViewer` but doesnt show data which I expect to be in report.

Comment: You need to post your client side code then so we can see the markup. Also I recommend posting a link to the reference docs. Finally, tag XtraReport and DevExpress so that people who have used the product before see your question.

Comment: I post everythink which I made. Client side code and Server Side Code as well.

Comment: I just had a look at the [docs](https://docs.devexpress.com/XtraReports/DevExpress.XtraReports.Web.ASPxWebDocumentViewer) and I can't see anywhere that the `ASPxWebDocumentViewer` provides client side functionality. `OpenReport` is a server side function. So I think in the first instance you should use your OnClick event to postback to the server (as it naturally does), load the report server side, then the page will refresh and display your report.

Comment: @DaleK I am gonna try this, but unfortunetly I have no idea how to do this. I couldnt find any example how does it work an what to code it.

Comment: Thank you @DaleK. I am gonna try something like this.